# proxy is undefined error backboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

```
 var my_variables = {};

_.extend(my_variables,Backbone.Events);

my_variables.on("event_name",function(msg)
{
   alert("easy street"+msg);
});

proxy.on("all", function(eventName) 
{
  my_variables.trigger(eventName);
});

my_variables.trigger("event_name");
```

Im trying to follow the code by reading the documentation, 
as far as I understood the proxy.on event is supposed to be called every time 
any event gets triggered.
On this code, I get the error message

> "proxy is not defined"

how to fix this 
here is the spot on the documentation
[documentation on events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on)!

Comment: @crypticous don't alter questions please, if you don't agree with something you can leave a comment.

Comment: I did't alter anything, just edited styling @ShadowWizard

Comment: @ShadowWizard What a childish !

Comment: @crypticous So probably the OP edited while you suggested the edit. It's always good practice to check for those things after editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code uses an example object (proxy) to do the call on..

For you to make it work you need to replace **proxy** with the name of your object.